# Connection many client fifo to one server fifo

Tags: c, fifo

have to write two programs (a client and a server) which will do
chatting with each other using FIFOs (to pass message from one process to another). The
server process creates a SERVER_FIFO to receive client connections only. The server
maintains the list of online clients. Each client creates its own CLIENT_FIFO to receive
commands from server to be executed at client using system() system call. You can use
getpid() system call to retrieve client’s process id to be concatenated in the
CLIENT_FIFO name.

I only to create 2 fifo that communicate with each other

## SERVER

```
// C program to implement one side of FIFO 
// This side writes first, then reads 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int fd; 

    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo"; 

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 

    char arr1[80], arr2[80]; 
    while (1) 
    { 

        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); 

        fgets(arr2, 80, stdin); 

        write(fd, arr2, strlen(arr2)+1); 
        close(fd); 

        // Open FIFO for Read only 
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY); 

        // Read from FIFO 
        read(fd, arr1, sizeof(arr1)); 

        // Print the read message 
        printf("User2: %s\n", arr1); 
        close(fd); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

==================================================================

## CLIENT

```
// C program to implement one side of FIFO 
// This side reads first, then reads 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int fd1; 

    // FIFO file path 
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo"; 

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 

    char str1[80], str2[80]; 
    while (1) 
    { 
        // First open in read only and read 
        fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY); 
        read(fd1, str1, 80); 

        // Print the read string and close 
        printf("User1: %s\n", str1); 
        close(fd1); 


        fd1 = open(myfifo,O_WRONLY); 
        fgets(str2, 80, stdin); 
        write(fd1, str2, strlen(str2)+1); 
        close(fd1); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Fifo is a wrong IPC primitive for *many* clients or bidirectional communication. You want to read about *Unix domain sockets*. It is so wrong that it hurts actually, I wonder who'd give this as an assignment